# How to write into <input type="hidden"> from Controller using POST method

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

what im trying is to write a simple boolean value to the value of the hidden field in the jsp:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createResource", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createCategory(@RequestParam("parentCategory") String parentCategory,                     
                             @ModelAttribute("SmartResources") Category category, ModelMap model, HttpSession session)
{
    model.addAttribute("resourceProperties", CategoryPropertyService.getInstance().getAllPropertiesById(Integer.parseInt(parentCategory))); 

    model.addAttribute("test", Boolean.TRUE);

    return "redirect:" + GlobalConstants.Dialog.DIALOG_BLANK;
}
```

JSP:

```
<input type="hidden" id="showPopUp" name="showPopUp" value="${test}" />
```

When i read the value of the hidden input with JQuery its always empty:

Script:

```
var popUpControl = $("#showPopUp").val();
var modal = $.UIkit.modal("#newResource");
if (popUpControl == true) {
    modal.show();   
}
```

When i do the same in a GET method of the same Controller the input field gets filled.

Please help me. There has to be a way to fill this input field from a post method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the attributes from the model to persist across redirect, you'll have to use a specialization of the Model interface, the RedirectAttributes

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createResource", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createCategory(@RequestParam("parentCategory") String parentCategory,                     
                             @ModelAttribute("SmartResources") Category category, ModelMap model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs, HttpSession session)
{
    redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("resourceProperties", CategoryPropertyService.getInstance().getAllPropertiesById(Integer.parseInt(parentCategory))); 

    redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("test", Boolean.TRUE);

    return "redirect:" + GlobalConstants.Dialog.DIALOG_BLANK;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. Now i have antoher Problem. i always get this error: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().

Comment: Found it. It was the boolean. Replaced it with a string and the syntax is correct. still the js part gets no value from the "test" attribute

Comment: sorry, I misslead you a bit, edited an answer again, instead of addAttribute, I've changed to addFlashAttribute, the first will append to redirect uri so you would have to access it via ${param.test}, now it will work for you